# .load() add a div before another div in the DOM (not inside)

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a site that is divided into 2 columns (each at 50% width):

HTML:

```
<nav></nav>
<div class="left-column"></div>
<div class="right-column"></div>
<footer></footer>
```

I have a secondary page with html:

```
<nav></nav>
<div class="left-column"></div>
<div class="right-column level-two"></div>
<footer></footer>
```

Using .load() I want to have the right-column on the secondary page load on top of the right-column of the first page (with the intention of adding a close box afterwards).

The html would look like this:

```
   <nav></nav>
   <div class="left-column"></div>
   <div class="right-column level-two"></div> //THE RIGHT COLUMN FROM LEVEL 2 INSERTED HERE
   <div class="right-column"></div>
   <footer></footer>
```

The problem is I can't figure out a way to do this:  .append() still adds it into the div it's attached to and .before() doesn't work to add jquery(?) just content?

I want the two right-columns to exist because if I close out `right-column level-two` I still want the original `right-column` underneath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `CSS` selector to search for the class `left-column` and it's neighbor class `right-column`
- Insert the data from `holder` in between the two classes

---

```
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $.get('second-page-url.html',function (data) {
        $(data).find('.right-column.level-two').insertBefore($('.left-column + .right-column'));
});
```

Comment: So there's no way to do it without inserting empty "holder" divs into the html? Also, I've seen examples just like this that use .load() with e.preventDefault(); - do I need that and if so, what default event would I be preventing?

Comment: @pappley I see absolutely no reason for using prevntDefault here. Also, if you don't want to load into holder just modify the code to use $.get - if this is what you want let me know and i'll change it - you can see jashwant's answer to see how to change it.

Comment: right, I would prefer to not add html in order to make this function. But does $get allow me to only .load (or at least filter out) a specific class/ID - I was unsure from reading

Comment: Yes, i'll update my example then i need to sleep :)

@pappley updated.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense (need to adjust html and will implement this) thanks!

Comment: @pappley Sure thing, if you need more help just leave a comment tagging my name and I'll see it tomorrow.

Comment: Okay, so I added a click function and I get nothing:

   `$(document).ready( function () {
  $('.button').click(function(){
   $.get('secondarypage/',function (data) {
   $(data).find('.right-column-level-two').insertBefore($('.left-column + .right-column'));
   });
  });
});`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27182/discussion-between-evan-and-pappley)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get('<secondary_page_url>',function (data) {
  $(data).find('.right-column.level-two').insertBefore($('.right-column'));
})
```

Comment: But this won't get specific data, it will pull the entire page - right?

Comment: Even `load()` pulls the entire data. `load()` is just a shortcut method (`load()` uses `$.get()` internally). It does the removal mechanism by itself after fetching the whole page.

Comment: But can't `load()` specify specific ID's too?

Comment: Yes, but it does fetch whole page. If I were using `load()`, I need not to filter content like this `$(data).find('.right-column.level-two')`

Comment: @EVan, from [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/), "When this (`load()`) method executes, it retrieves the content of ajax/test.html, but then jQuery parses the returned document to find the element with an ID of container. This element, along with its contents, is inserted into the element with an ID of result, and the rest of the retrieved document is discarded"

Comment: Right, so in this case the user could use `.load` to directly parse the returned data for `.right-column`, right?

Comment: Yes, but that will involve overhead (creating another div) etc